# VB .NET function that calls a C++ COM Method that receives variants as outs

Tags: c++, .net, vb.net, com

I have racked my brain and almost killed my keyboard trying to manage to make this work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am creating a VB .NET app that is a helper app for another system.  I have access to the API for the application that I am accessing.  Long story short, here is the C++ COM Function that I need to call:

```
RecordSearch(RemoteServer,ScreenName,FieldData,ObjId,Flags,MaxHitCount,ResultSet,ScreenDef,OASError)
```

- Remote Server = [IN] Dispatch - Object to the connection, Nothing can be used if already connected
- ScreenName = [IN] String - Name of the screen to use
- FieldData = [IN] Dispatch - Object of the data to be found, Nothing is acceptable
- ObjId = [IN] Dispath - Object of the file to be found
- Flags = [IN] Long - Always 0, future use
- MaxHitCount = [IN] Long - Max number of records to retrieve (0 returns all)
- ResultSet = [OUT] Variant - Record Array of the records found
- ScreenDef = [OUT] Variant - Screen Definition that describes the screen
- OASError = [OUT] Long - Returns 0 if successful or error from server if not

I have access to declare the ResultSet & ScreenDef different ways.  My issue is that I keep getting a Type Mismatch error when I attempt to pass the function in this manner:

```vb
Dim Optix8 As OptixRemoteServer = New OptixRemoteServer()
Dim Optix8WS As Object = CreateObject("Optix8.Application")

Optix8WS.ServerSelect("Mac")

If (Optix8WS.ServerLogon("########")) Then
    Dim screen_name = "Claims"
    Dim myFieldData As Object = Nothing
    Dim myObjectId = CreateObject("Optix8.Objid")
    myObjectId.FromString("oas:/12000/file/22")
    Dim Flags As Long = 0
    Dim MaxHitCount As Long = 0
    Dim myResultSet As Object = Nothing
    Dim myScreenDef As Object = Nothing
    Dim OASError = Nothing
    Try
        Dim result = Optix8WS.RecordSearch(Nothing, screen_name, myFieldData, myObjectId, Flags, MaxHitCount, myResultSet, myScreenDef, OASError)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End If
```

The issue is with the myResultSet & myScreenDef I believe.  I don't fully understand how to pass the [out] of those two to the empty objects that are created.  I have done this in C# by using out and ref but, those are not feasible in VB.NET.

Am I missing something?  How would I accomplish this?  I am not very big on VB.NET.  I am a C# programmer.

Comment: Change Long to Integer.

Comment: That didn't change anything.  I don't think it has anything to do with the Types.  I think it has more to do with the lack of [out] in VB.NET.  I could be wrong.  That's why I'm here.  :)

Comment: It doesn't lack [out], it is ByRef.  You just don't have to write it in the call.  There's somebody that can debug your problem but nobody can help you pick up the telephone.

Comment: I'm confused how I add ByRef into the function so that it passes the memory location of myResultSet & myScreenDef objects to the COM function.  I have looked all over the internet for answers and everything I have found is talking about how to create a function using ByRef.  The problem is that I do not have the ability to create the function, it is already in the COM which I cannot change.

Comment: So, I figured out that the API documentation was incorrect.  After looking into the header files, I realized that the Remote Server had to be assigned to the IDispatch of the already connected server.  Thanks for the help!